# detect rotate gesture and scale gesture iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, touch

I want to rotate the uiimageview also scale the image view so how do i detect touch gesture that user is scaling or user is rotating?

Answer (score 1):

Beginning in iOS 3.2, Apple introduced the use of `UIGestureRecognizer`'s. The two that you would be interested in are `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`.  To use a pinch gesture you could do the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchGesture:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:pinch];
    [pinch release];
}

- (void)handlePinchGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"New Scale: %f", sender.scale);
}
```

You could do something similar for the `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` then.

Comment: NSLog(@"New Scale: %f", sender.scale);
 It's also gives error while compiling like this "error: request for member 'scale' in something not a structure or union"

Comment: I want to do it without using UIGestureRecognizer is there a way to do both on touchMoved?

Comment: You can do it in touchMoved, but it will be more complicated.  You will need to get the locations of the touch and create a bounding box for those touches. Then you can scale the image view based on that bounding rectangle.

Comment: could you please tell me how it can be done? it might be complicated but it's not impossible....

Answer (score 0):

in your viewcontroller.h file write down this properties

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *imgRotate;
CGFloat lastScale;
CGFloat lastRotation;
```

now in your viewcontroller.m file write the below code,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
[pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[imgRotate addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
[rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[imgRotate addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];
}

-(void)scale:(id)sender
{
if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    lastScale = 1.0;
    return;
}

CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]);

CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

[[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

[imgRotate setTransform:newTransform];
lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
}

-(void)rotate:(id)sender
{
if([(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    lastRotation = 0.0;
    return;
}

CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (lastRotation - [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation]);

CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform,rotation);

[[(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

[imgRotate setTransform:newTransform];
lastRotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

if ([touch view] == imgRotate) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    imgRotate.center = location;
}
}
```